Pyrebase does not return credentials
I was working for firebase login system using pyrebase, and I found that auth in the code below does not work correctly.
'apiKey': "",
            'authDomain': "",
            'databaseURL': "",
            'projectId': "",
            'storageBucket': "",
            'appId': "",
            'measurementId': "",
            'serviceAccountId': '',
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
        auth = firebase.auth()
        print(auth.credentials)
        user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(self.id, self.pw1)
        uid = user['localId']
        print(user)
        idToken = auth.create_custom_token(uid,expiry_minutes=1440)
        print(idToken)

In this code, I think print(auth.credentials)  must output something, but it keeps showing None. Since it create and account using email and password, auth() itself is working but fails to get credentials, eventually creating custom token impossible.
What should I do to create token ?
